# Load pdf maps on iOS using ArcGis Api

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

I exported a layer and features attribute to PDF using ArcGis software. And now, I would like to build an iOS app that I can load this map offline. as I just have started to use ArcGis for iOS, I tried tried this code and I could'n see this map:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.map = AGSMap(basemap: AGSBasemap.topographic())
    self.mapView.map = map
    let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Map1", withExtension: "pdf")
    let localTiledLayer = AGSArcGISTiledLayer(tileCache: AGSTileCache(fileURL: path!))
    self.mapView.map = map
    map.operationalLayers.add(localTiledLayer)
}
```

How do I load this pdf file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF maps are not supported by the Runtime.

If you want to export feature data, you should use Mobile Map Packages, which can be generated by ArcGIS Pro. They package up a map (or many maps) with data, symbology, popup configuration etc. and can be opened using the [AGSMobileMapPackage](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_mobile_map_package.html) class.

If you are using ArcMap, then you could export a Runtime Geodatabase and open that using the [AGSGeodatabase](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_geodatabase.html) class, but Mobile Map Packages provide more capabilities in a single file rather than having to create maps and load layers from various sources.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xM9On_P5F_I) gives a good overview of what's possible, and you can read more [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/features/offline/).